# Youtube Videos Thumbnail

Tags: php, json, video, youtube

I am using this code to get related videos. With this code I get title and link of the video. How can I get the thumb of the video?

```
<?php
$JSON = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/FYpunY-gXxU/related?v=2&alt=json");
$JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON);
$title = $JSON_Data->{'feed'}->{'entry'};
for ($i = 1; $i < 25; $i++)
{
    echo ($title[$i]->{'title'}->{'$t'}) . "<br />";
    echo $title[$i]->{'link'}[0]->{'href'} . "<br /><br />";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the `json_decode`, the best way is to print the entire result for yourself and then see the necessary data you have to get...

Do this:

```
`<?php
$JSON = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/FYpunY-gXxU/related?v=2&alt=json");
$JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($JSON_Data);
?>`
```

You'll get to know what exactly you have to extract...
I leave that to you...  :)

Answer (score 0):

I would :-

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/FYpunY-gXxU/related?v=2&alt=json");
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach((array)$json_data['feed']['entry'] as $video){

echo $video['title']['$t'].'<br/>';
echo $video['link'][0]['href'].'<br/>'; 

?>
<img src="<?php echo $video['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][0]['url']?>" />
<img src="<?php echo $video['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][1]['url']?>" />
<?php    
}
?>
```

Comment: Updated my answer.See the json response structure to learn more using print_r or firebug.

Comment: Add &max-results=5 to the URL and for more Read the manual https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#Video_Feeds